# Is localizing Swagger UI possible?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, localization, swagger, swagger-ui

Is it possible to have localized swagger UI for aspnet core web api?

I found [blog](https://medium.com/@k.khodaei/how-to-generate-multilingual-documents-api-in-asp-net-core-and-swagger-e8a48d1bd31f) about generating localized summaries, but Swagger UI itself stays in english. Also described approach works only once for first request and it is not possible to regenerate swagger.json with other language.

Comment: Neither Swagger UI nor OpenAPI Specification support localization.